# IOS/Objective-C: Deleting row and coreData in Editing Style method - UITable

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I believe this is a simple task, but so far I'm only able to delete the row itself but not the CoreData. The code I'm trying to write - fetch and NSManaged Object is not working, and I'm a bit confused. Can someone help me out? What I've got:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

     NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Spot"];

     NSManagedObject *managedObject = [request objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
     [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

     //delets the row but not the core data
     [_locations removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


     [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

 }
 }
```

Comment: Check `error.localizedDescription` by passing NSError *error, `&error` in `[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way and in this order:

- Get the object from the data source array by index(path).
- Delete the object in the context.
- Save the context and check the error.
- On success remove the object from the data source array and delete the row in the table view.

---

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

      NSManagedObject *objectToDelete = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject: objectToDelete];
      NSError *error;
      [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
      if (error) { 
          NSLog(@"Could not save managed object context due to error: %@", error); 
      } else {
          [_locations removeObject:objectToDelete];
          [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post vadian, but the data is still there. I insert new spot, delete the row, stop the app, restart and the spot is still there...Isn't needed a fecth?

Comment: No, a fetch is not needed if the data source array is populated once by a fetch. Is `managedObjectContext` not `nil`? Consider to use `NSFetchedResultController`. It makes a few things more convenient.

Comment: and if I put this way:  if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"%@", error);
     }
I get null

Comment: Well, I never used the NSFetchedResultController...is that different?

Comment: Please check that the managed object context contains a valid object. The result controller manages the update of the table view and more. For example you don't need an extra data source array.

Comment: well, the log says null...I dont get it becausr _locations is the array where the new spot goes (and each time I insert one the table updates) Do you need to see more code? Thank your for your kindness

Comment: If `managedObjectContext` is `nil` it does not save without throwing an error. If not the code in my answer is supposed to work. Usually you get the managed object context from the Core Data stack in `AppDelegate`.

Comment: My managed object context is not in AppDelegate. Can this be the issue?

Comment: Could be. Make sure that your app uses **always** the same instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`. That's why Apple suggests to place it in `AppDelegate`. The alternative way is a singleton class.